# iPhone - programmatically select language keyboards

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, internationalization, keyboard-events

I'm writing some apps that have multiple languages. I know I can set up the devices to have international keyboards.

What would be terrific is if there was a way to select the English keyboard for the english words and the specific foreign keyboard for each language that I use.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to disappoint you, but what you're asking is simply not possible.

Comment: I do know that the user can select the keyboard. I also know what languages my app uses (it's part of a series that teaches greek). I should have said more in my original post. Is it worth an enhancement request?

Comment: and Erik, your comment was exactly what I needed to know. Thanks +1

Comment: Hi, I'm from the future. This is possible now… http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595970/iphone-change-keyboard-language-programmatically

Answer (score 3):

It's up to the user which keyboards they use at all times. If they have multiple languages enabled then they can switch between them freely without leaving the view, as an extra button is added for the purpose. You can't give a hint as to which language the user is likely to want.

Those properties you can adjust are given by the [UITextInputTraits protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html), so that should give a full list of things you can specify. I believe they're all exposed on the relevant controls by Interface Builder and/or Xcode 4, so shouldn't be much of a surprise.