# Language in UITextField

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I've got two textfields with userName and userEmail. I want userName field to show keyboard with system default language and userEmail field to show keyboard always in english. How to do this?

Comment: You can't. Keyboard language is up to the user. But you can ask for UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress.

Comment: But if I set keyboard type to EmailAddress it's still would be in system language

Comment: Yes, that is what I said.

Comment: According to this answer, it may be possible in iOS 7: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23403247/2274694

Comment: @matt, since user2685238 is trying to override the system language, how would asking for UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress help in this case?

Comment: It wouldn't. It is a thing he can do, that's all. He can set the keyboard type. But not, it seems, the language.