# I want to support localisation in my iOS app but i want my keyboard to be English only. Is it possible?

Tags: ios, iphone, localization, keyboard, internationalization

My ios app support localisation to display label/images according to the iphone's preferred language. But this also changes the keyboard to that specified language. But can I disable that in my code so that the keyboard appeared is in english only and all other feature(apart from keyboard) supports localisation.

I have the answer for displaying english keyboard [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595970/iphone-change-keyboard-language-programmatically).
But I also want to disable user from switching to other keyboards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone: Change Keyboard language programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595970/iphone-change-keyboard-language-programmatically)

Comment: This question has already been answered here. You should search a bit more before you ask a question. See the answer with 8, upvotes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595970/iphone-change-keyboard-language-programmatically

Comment: @CliffRibaudo Do you know the answer to the **second** part.

Answer (score 1):

Set keyboardType property of UITextField to UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable and the keyoboard will be english only

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;
```