# Why iOS convert English numbers to Arabic at UITextField using Swift language and iOS 15?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikit, ios15

I have an application that supported 2 languages English and Arabic when changing the app language to Arabic all UITextFields support Arabic numbers only.

For example:
When writing an email "**test123@gmail.com**"
It appears at UITextField "**test١٢٣@gmail.com**"

I tried to set

```
    txtFldEmail.textField.keyboardType = .asciiCapable
    txtFldEmail.textField.textContentType = .emailAddress
```

And also,

```
    @objc func txtFldChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
         textField.text = textField.text?.arToEnIfNeeded
    }
```

But no changes happen still UITextField writes numbers in Arabic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting keyboard to a textfield to English language only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814134/setting-keyboard-to-a-textfield-to-english-language-only)

Comment: No, I want the keyboard in English and Arabic no problem, but when the app is in the Arabic language I want to write English numbers in UITextField, and that does not happen and numbers are converted to Arabic numbers.