# Why UITextInputMode.activeInputModes() crash on Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I had been working making a swift implementation of this question [iPhone: Change Keyboard language programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595970/iphone-change-keyboard-language-programmatically?lq=1) but I found something that i can't figure out how to fix,

**This method crash my application**

```
UITextInputMode.activeInputModes() //this crashes
```

**This method is the analog in swift of this method in Objective C**

```
 [UITextInputMode activeInputModes] //this works ok
```

**This is the crash**

[image: Screen Shot]

So my question is: Is this a bug in Swift? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Crashes how? Update your question with relevant details of the crash.

Comment: ok, I will put more details sorry

Comment: @rmaddy my question was edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug of iOS 9 SDK.

Objective-C header as follows:

```
+ (NSArray<NSString *> *)activeInputModes; // The activate input modes.
```

This should be:

```
+ (NSArray<UITextInputMode *> *)activeInputModes; // The activate input modes.
```

A dirty workaround:

```
let aaa = (UITextInputMode.self as AnyObject as! NSObject).performSelector("activeInputModes").takeRetainedValue()
```

You should send a Bug Report to Apple soon.

Answer (score 1):

UITextInputMode.activeInputModes() returns the wrong type and crashes in Xcode 7, see [here](http://www.openradar.me/22643142) .

And how to avoid it , I saw the solution to it likes this(create a bridge between OC and swift):

MyMethod.h

```
#import <UIKit/UITextInput.h>

@interface MyMethod: NSObject

+ (NSArray<UITextInputMode *> *)activeInputModes;

@end
```

MyMethod.m

```
#import "MyMethod.h"
 @implementation MyMethod

+ (NSArray<UITextInputMode *> *)activeInputModes {
return (NSArray<UITextInputMode *> *)[UITextInputMode activeInputModes];
}
@end
```

Bridge.h

```
#import "MyMethod.h"
```

You can now call MyMethod.activeInputModes() and get the correct results in swift.