# How to present the arabic keyboard while changing the application language to arabic?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, arabic

I have a mobile application which supports the Arabic and English language. So for this i am using two separate storyboard to flip the layout right to left while changing the language(Not sure whether its a good thinking of using two separate storyboard for Arabic and Malayalam. Please do suggest of any other better solution).

But thats not the case i wish to present the user with Arabic keyboard while changing the application language to Arabic for filling the registration form. How to achieve this in Swift 3?

```
    - (void)reloadStoryboard
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard;

    switch ([AALanguageManager getCurrentLanguage]) {

        case CurrentLanguageRTL:
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardRTL" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            break;
        default:
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardLTR" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            break;
    }

    self.window.rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: If you are using autolayout then there is no need to use two storyboards.

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23403247/4763963. It may help you!