# How to show Hebrew keyboard when the application language is changed to the Hebrew in swift3?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, keyboard

I have an iOS application which has two languages English and Hebrew. When the application is switched to the Hebrew i want to show the Hebrew keyboard to the UITextField as the Text input mode.

Currently i have seen the following links but i a haven't got any clear idea.

[How to present the arabic keyboard while changing the application language to arabic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931861/how-to-present-the-arabic-keyboard-while-changing-the-application-language-to-ar)

[iPhone: Change Keyboard language programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595970/iphone-change-keyboard-language-programmatically/23403247#23403247)

Please do help me with the Swift3 code here or any useful idea or snippet fro your side.