# How to change region (language) in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, localization, keyboard, region

I need to force the language to "es_MX" instead of only "es", as there are differences in keyboard for example ("." instead of ",")
I know language ("es") can be forced, but is there a way to force region too? Or any other approach to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, my client thinks differently though.
I just need to know how to do that, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After googling a little I am pretty much convinced that an app does not have the capability to force a language on a user in iOS. However, following the hints in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595970/iphone-change-keyboard-language-programmatically) you should be able to choose among the available keyboards by overriding `textInputMode` of your `UITextField` and checking on `UITextInputMode.activeInputModes`. I am not sure how this will represent the region, but since the keyboards seem to differ they should be distinguishable at this point.