# Is it possible to change keyboard language according to change language in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift3

Is it possible to change keyboard language according to change language in ios swift
if possible help me for this, thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "according to change language"?

Comment: the keyboard language can only be changed by the user of the device, if you thinking about forcing one in your application?    https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht202178

Comment: @NicoHaase according to language change of application, if application is in Arabic then keyboard language should be in Arabic, without adding it in settings, So is it possible

Comment: @zero3nna i change my application language , so now i want keyboard language is in that language, yes am thinking about forcing application to change keyboard language

Answer (score 0):

You have to override textInputMode method of UITextField and then you can set your primary language.

Comment: can you show me some example

Comment: but by using this, language of keyboard will not change, it will change type of keyboard, like email, phone, etc

Comment: yeah, that's true, mode will change only .ascii , .numpad etc. but no the language, until iOS 13, you can try overriding the primary language. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595970/iphone-change-keyboard-language-programmatically