# Keyboard Localization of type Decimal Pad

Tags: ios, localization, keyboard, swift4, french

I am trying below code for keyboard localization which work in Swift3.
I have taken this code from below link:-
[iPhone: Change Keyboard language programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595970/iphone-change-keyboard-language-programmatically)

But it gives below error in Swift 4.

a) `let language = type.getKeyboardLanguage()`
for this line it gives error as:- `Expression type '(_) -> _' is ambiguous without more context`

b)In switch case for below code

```
switch self {
        case .one:
            return "en"
        case .two:
            return "ru"
        case .three:
            return ""
        case .four:
            return ""
        }
```

It gives error as `Pattern cannot match values of type 'ViewController' for cases in Switch`.

```
override var textInputMode: UITextInputMode? {


        let language = type.getKeyboardLanguage()
        if language.isEmpty {
            return super.textInputMode

        } else {
            for tim in UITextInputMode.activeInputModes {
                if tim.primaryLanguage!.contains(language) {
                    return tim
                }
            }
            return super.textInputMode
        }

    }
    func getKeyboardLanguage() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .one:
            return "en"
        case .two:
            return "ru"
        case .three:
            return ""
        case .four:
            return ""
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define a type that your function is expected to return.

```
let language: SomeTypeHere = type.getKeyboardLanguage()
```

Cheers!

Comment: it is giving error to type. I have tried with below line:-
 let language : String = type.getKeyboardLanguage()
Still it is giving error as Expression type '(_) -> _' is ambiguous without more context.

Comment: Then you need to check where you define the type.getKeyboardLanguage() function.  You might have some <T> generics in there that cause this to not work in Swift4