# How to change keyboard language in Search Bar? Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, textfield, searchbar

How can I change language in TextField:

```swift
class langField: UITextField {
    var languageCode:String? {
        didSet {
            if self.isFirstResponder {
                self.resignFirstResponder()
                self.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }
    
    override var textInputMode: UITextInputMode? {
        if let language_code = self.languageCode {
            for keyboard in UITextInputMode.activeInputModes {
                if let language = keyboard.primaryLanguage {
                    let locale = Locale.init(identifier: language)
                    if locale.languageCode == language_code {
                        return keyboard
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return super.textInputMode
    }
}
```

Then:

```swift
let textFiled = langField()
textField.languageCode = "en"
```

And when user taps on your TextField language will become English

**How to do the same for the search bar?**

I do this:

```swift
extension UISearchBar {
    
    func textField() -> UITextField? {
        
        for view in subviews {
            
            for subview in view.subviews {
                
                if let textField = subview as? UITextField {
                    return textField
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

But when I call `textField` there is no `.languageCode` method

Comment: Same with this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595970/iphone-change-keyboard-language-programmatically