# How to set TextInputType as Korean language?

Tags: dart, keyboard, flutter

I have to implement TextInputType as Korean for the TextField, but default `TextInputType.text` is only English.

How can I set this option as my specific language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now this feature is not implemented in current version of the Flutter. Issue already posted https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25841

So it good for you to don't fight with it and wait.

Comment: Dude Flutter not poor,  I thought it's also not possible in Native even https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595970/iphone-change-keyboard-language-programmatically