# How to show only English keyboard in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, ios14

I'm developing an iOS application, Xcode 12.4 & iOS 14.4. Trying to show only English keyboard even though the user has multiple languages related keyboards.

Is it possible to show only English keyboard irrespective of the device language?

Is there any global setting to do this?

Comment: see this may be it helps you : [iPhone: Change Keyboard language programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595970/iphone-change-keyboard-language-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind which language the app uses, you can set app language yourself , try this code:

```
    let lang = "en"
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(lang, forKey: "AppleLanguage")
defaults.synchronize()
Bundle.setLanguage(lang)
// Restart your app by setting window rootViewcontroller
```

Comment: Thanks. It didn't work. It didn't set to English keyboard, and the User is still able to switch the keyboard between languages.