# Make SwiftUI display localized decimal pad with region decimal separator

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to display decimal pad for input on a based on the country selected in the app by the user. I keep getting the decimal point on the keyboard even though I'm using a NumberFormatter with the country's locale to format the input.

```
struct AmountTextField: View {
  let countryLocale: Locale
  @State private var text = ""

  var formatter: NumberFormatter {
       let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.locale = countryLocale 
        formatter.currencyGroupingSeparator = ","
        formatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = true
        formatter.allowsFloats = true
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        return formatter
  }

  var body: some View {
      TextField("Enter amount", text: $text)
         .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
         .onChange(of: text) { newValue in
            ...
            text = formatter.string(for: newValue)!
         }
  }
}
```

How do I achieve this? For instance, its meant to display comma(,) as decimal separator for Angola.

Comment: Your formatter isn't affecting the keyboard because its job is to only format numbers. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595970/iphone-change-keyboard-language-programmatically) for changing the keyboard language.